# How can I rename a group of variables in a loop in MATLAB?

Tags: excel, matlab

I have imported a matrix `X` filled with data, and its according headers for each column into MATLAB. Now the problem is how can I rename each column of `X` by its according name in the header cell.
I would like to do this in a loop.
Would anyone tell me how can I loop a rename programme in this situation?

Comment: Can you provide an example? It sounds like eval() can do what you need, but there is probably a cleaner way

Comment: Hi, I use this code: [X,header,~] = xlsread('eaef21.xls',1,'A1:AY541'); Then I have header in the cell 'header' and all data in matrix 'X', each column of X is a dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest creating a [structure](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/struct.html) out of the data, rather than individual variables.  Even with a large number of columns, this will not clutter the workspace, nor will it overwrite variables already in the workspace in the case of a name collision.  It will keep all the data from the spreadsheet together, and still allowing access to it by column name.  To easily create a structure from a cell array of column names and a matrix of data, use [cell2struct](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cell2struct.html):

```
>> colnames = {'odds','evens'};
>> data = [1 2;3 4;5 6];
>> spreadsheet_structure = cell2struct(num2cell(data,1), colnames, 2)

spreadsheet_structure = 

     odds: [3x1 double]
    evens: [3x1 double]
```

(`num2cell(M,1)` creates a cell array in which each cell is a column from matrix `M`)

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the header columns and use eval to create variables with names contained as strings in your matrix "header":

```
  [X,header,~] = xlsread('eaef21.xls',1,'A1:AY541');
  for H = 1:size(header,2)
     eval([header(1,H), " = X(:,", H, ");"]);
  end
```

Also it is often very useful to replace the `eval` above with `disp` until you are satisfied that it is working as you want it to. Using `disp` will help you understand what is going on as well.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but the MATLAB reports: eval(header(1,H) + " = X(:," + H + ");");      
                        |
Error: The input character is not valid in MATLAB statements or expressions.

Comment: Did you try it with disp() instead of eval() first? Use disp for debugging eval statements. What is the output of header(1,1)?

Comment: Try this again. There was a syntax error, I was using C# string concatenation syntax. Thanks to EitanT for editing.